# Access view-source instead of prepared DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hopefully I can explain my question correctly, so sorry in advance for any wrong use of jargon or other:
Is it possible to access with javascript the original markup as viewed in the source code rather then the code from the DOM after it has been 'modified'
Let's say an element #div1 has the actual text that will be used in another element with id #div2, in the source code the text will be visible in #div1 but in the DOM while inspecting #div1 will be empty and #div2 will have that text,
I know it would be a matter of the order of loading the scripts, but I was hoping there could be another way.
Hopefully this makes some sense.

Comment: maybe send an ajax request and get full raw respond text.

Comment: Use $(document).ready to register you function. You will have to load your script first in the page, so your callback will be executed first. Inside your callback you can save the full HTML of the current page or sections of it with `.html()` e.g. `var x = $('html').html();`

Comment: From what I understood you want to cut out text from #div1 after the page is loaded and paste it into #div2. Is that correct?

Comment: Hey, it doesn't matter that much what needs to be done the with the example elements, I only want to know if I can access the original html in let's say a window.onload, so after the DOM has been prepared, sorry for any confusion in my question.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the simpliest way to access original html is to place your js code before any other scripts (or place only libs like jquery before).

The second opportunity is to load document again with ajax, parse and get what you want. Here is code example:

```
    <div id="div1">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div id="div2">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#div2').html($('#div1').html())
        $('#div1').html('')
    </script>
    <script>
        alert($('#div1').html())
        // ajax get
        // empty string in get request means current location
        $.get("", function (html) {
            var el = $(html).filter('#div1');
            alert(el.html())
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @DimalIt, this returns as undefined for me:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtp4y700/)

Comment: I specially avoid jsfiddle because requests can behave unexpectedly there.
Here is inner window from your fiddle: [link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/gtp4y700/show/).
For me it's works fine.
But of course it's better to test on your own page.
UPD: original fiddle works too, if you refresh page and not click run.